# Finding container values span (with early exit)

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Given a vector of (random) numbers, I'm looking for the magnitude difference between the smallest element and the largest element. The STL has the `minmax_element` function for this purpose. Depending on the result, I would like to perform some action in my code, i.e., if the difference is large enough, I would like to `do stuff`.

Right now, my code looks as follow:

```cpp
    auto res = std::minmax_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    if (std::abs(*res.second - *res.first) > threshold)
      // do stuff
```

This algorithm works in principle. However, in most of my cases the `if` condition will be fulfilled. I would even bet in most of my cases I can simply compare the first and the second element in my vector in order to check the `if` condition and do stuff.
Having said this, it seems a bit odd that I run through the whole vector all the time, although I mostly don't have to. Is there a STL-algorithm, which takes the early exit into, or has someone an appropriate STL algorithm solution in mind. I could easily write a hand-crafted for-loop with an early exit in order to do what I want, but maybe there are better options.

Comment: But if you have vector of random numbers, how would you know when to do a early exit? And also, do you have performarce issues? What is the reason for optimizing in this example? If your code works fine, then what is the motivation for optimizing it?

Comment: I know when to exit early when two numbers already have a difference larger than the threshold value. Example: given a vector `{1, 5, 7, 4, 6, 20, 3}` and I want to do things if the difference of the maximum and minimum value is greater than `2`. Computing the difference here between the first two elements would be sufficient to enter the `if` branch, right?
Right now, I don't have performance issues and modifying this would mostly be cosmetic. However, it could become performance critical in a later phase.

Comment: Aha, I understand. I think that some optimizations in the algorithms library depends on them never exiting early. I thought about sending a custom lambda as a comparison operator to std::minmax(), that keeps track of the difference, but I don't think there is a way to exit early.

Comment: `std::find_if` with a stateful predicate could likely be made to work; the predicate would return `true` as soon as it's seen two elements with large enough difference.